# Child (inner) Path of backend in Virtual Host is possible?

Tags: structure, install, server, installation, composer

I have ISP Config host virtual website which is a system tool to host many websites. **Document root** path '/' is not writable. I have an **/private**, which is writable. I used alias **@root** as **/private**, and I set in index.php this path as CRAFT_BASE_PATH. When I try to install plugins I have the following error:

```
Error: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/clients/client0/web7/.composer/cache) is not within the allowed path(s):
The web7/.composer is not writable
```

How to fix this issue and let CraftCMS create **temporary** .composer/cache folder in **@root alias** path (/private folder), instead of the default **DOCUMENT ROOT** path?

The website public is in /web folder, for backend (not publicly shared) is in /private in ISP Config, and DOC_ROOT (/) is not writable.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to modify your php.ini's [open_basedir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) setting, the simplest solution would be to add `/var/www/clients/client0/web7/.composer` as an allowed path to it so PHP can write to it.